# How to just take the numbers with MessageHandler

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

i am making a telegram bot and i have a question :
How can i just take the numbers and deny other type to run callback with MessageHandler? my framework is python-telegram-bot

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: i think you don't need my code , its clear how can i put filter in first argument of MessageHandler to just allow the number to run callback(second argument)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's so that we won't have to set up a whole development environment, install libraries, code an example just to solve a problem that's possibly unrelated to your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : 
Using this code `MessageHandler(Filters.regex(r'\d+'), callback)`